# Does data:image behave differently for Firefox/Opera?

Tags: image, firefox, uri, data-uri

I have used the data:image URI to set the source of an image tag.

By default, the CSS `display` property is `none`. 
When I get the image from the user, I change the source on this tag and it shows the image:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64:............" />
```

My questions are:

**1.** Even though the display is `none`, I suspect the browser is still fetching the image. Am I right?

While fetching the browser should hit my server with relative URL. But sometimes it appends the source URI data to my absolute URL.... ONLY sometimes!!

```
/my-context/data:image/gif;base64....
```

**2.** Is this behavior expected? Is it browser specific?
I am seeing the requests from Firefox 5.0 and below and Opera 10.0 and below causing this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. This is not expected in a stock Firefox install.  Can you link to the page that shows the problem?

Comment: Sorry I cannot show on live page.

My apache access_log show entry of URL '/my-context/data:image/gif;base64....' as result of redirection from main page, which is not expected.
But when I access main page, it show not show this issue (even after clearing cache).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's entirely possible that some of the users of the page have some extension installed that screws things up.  It's hard to say any more than that given the data so far...